# Algorithm for 'good' number

Tags: php, algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

A give number x is 'good' if the sum of any two consecutive digit of the number x are between k and 2k.
I need to find an algorithm that for a given number k and a given number n, find how many 'good' n-digit numbers exist.

I made an implementation for this in PHP, but the complexity is to big (i am searching for all those 'good' number and counting them, so the complexity is O(10^n)).

```
<?php
    $n = 5;
    $k = 5;

    $min = $k*1;
    $max = $k*2;
    $counter = 0;

    for ($i = pow(10, $n-1); $i<pow(10,$n); $i++)
    {
        $number = $i;
        $prev = $number % 10;
        $number = $number / 10;

        while($number >= 10)
        {
            $crnt = $number % 10;
            $number = $number / 10;
            if ( ($crnt+$prev) > $min AND ($crnt+$prev) < $max ) {
                echo "good number: $i\n";
                $counter++;
            }
            $prev = $crnt;
        }
    }

    echo "counter: ".$counter."\n";
?>
```

Can someone confirm me if this can be the solution:

```
n=100 // given
k=10  // given

counter = 0;

for(i=10; i<100; i++)
{
    if( (i/10)+(i%10) > k ) && ( (i/10)+(i%10) < 2*k )
        counter++;
}

total = counter^(n-1)
```

Comment: Great post, good info, but smells of homework to me. We believe in you, you can do it!

Comment: Right now it says i%10+i%10 is <k and >2k.  I'm nearly positive that isn't what you were going for.  Try flipping the < and >

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I wanted to put OR instead of the AND, fixed the code now, but still looking if it is the solution.

Comment: Why do you think that algorithm should work?

Comment: Hi, it's best not to remove a question - I think you can only vote to delete it if it doesn't already have answers. Anyway, it's best left - this looks like it could be useful for someone else. Don't worry about the undeclared dvote, they happen to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

All those calls to `pow` certainly won't be helping.

What you can do is make a mapping of all the two-digit numbers that are 'good'.  Once you have your mapping, all you need to do is check that every pair of digits in your number is good.  You can do this by successive division by 10 and modulo 100.

Something like this would do the trick, provided you don't give it a negative number, and assuming you've set up your `$good` array.

```
function isgood( $num ) {
    while( $num >= 100 && $good[$num%100] ) {
        $num /= 10;
    }
    return $good[$num%100];
}
```

The next most obvious thing to do is memoize larger sequences.  This is a dynamic programming principle.  We've already memoized small sequences by storing the 'goodness' of 2-digit sequences.  But you could easily use those to generate sequences of 3, 4, 5, 6 digits...  Whatever your available memory allows.  Use the memos you already have in order to generate the sequences with one extra digit.

So, if you built up memoisation for up to 5-digit numbers, then you divide by 1000 every time, and get a great speedup.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the number of "not good numbers" with `n` digits and top digit `d` is a straightforward dynamic programming problem.

`10^n` is the number of "good numbers" plus "not good numbers".

I will give you no more help than that.

Comment: @MoritzRodd When I say "I will give no more help" I mean it.  Your problem sounds to me like bonus homework or some contest, and I don't want to hand it to you on a silver platter.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm counts how many 2 digit integers are **NOT** good. Then it returns this value to the power of `n - 1`. This should get you the number of `n` digit numbers that are NOT good. If you subtract this value from the total amount of `n` digit integers, you should get what you want. Or we could avoid doing this by changing the signs:

```
for($i=10; $i<100; $i++) {
 if( ($i/10) + ($i%10) > $k && ($i/10) + ($i%10) < 2*$k ) {
  $cnt++;
 }
}
$result = pow($cnt, $n-1);
```

This should get you the number of good `n` digit integers, but let's see if that's really the case.

Well, `cnt` will give the number of good 2 digit integers. So, on the first two positions, we can put any of these `cnt`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
x y
```

Then, what about positions 1 and 2? Well, position 1 is fixed by the first placement.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 ...
x y
  y z
```

So we have to prove that there are `cnt` possibilities for `z`, and I don't see why this should be the case, so I would say that the algorithm is wrong. Your algorithm will probably overcount.